# Protected execution from a discord bot

Tags: node.js, security, discord.js

I am writing a discord bot that would get python code (or any other interpreted langueages) from a message, save it to a file, execute it and send back the contents of stdout.
However, I guess it's a big secure risk, everybody could read or write outside of the directory, my discord bot is in.

My idea: in the shell of android I used proot to simulate a protected file system in a folder. Maybe I could do it in a similar way?

I am using Node.js for my discord bot.

Comment: why would you even want to do that? No offence but that seems pretty unsmart to me.

Comment: @Worthy yup, it is unsmart. However I do this on challenge and also it would be nice, if everyone could execute code, even if they have no PC currently. Because it won't matter, if you are sending message from phone or computer. There is of course Termux, but executing it on a computer would still be faster imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with `spawn` and `firejail --private=env [command_to_execute]`, works perfectly